# Select frames whose items belonk to keepers 1 and 2

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

```
class Frame(models.Model):
     pass

class Item(models.Model):

    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    keeper = models.ForeignKey(Person,
                               related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                               related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",
                               blank=False,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               verbose_name=_("Keeper"))
```

This is a photo archive. There are frames, items and keepers of items.
Now, I've got a string representing keepers.

```
keeper_and_list = '1 2'
```

I'd like to extract Frames whose items belong to keepers 1 AND 2.

```
keeper_and_list = keeper_and_str.split()
keeper_and_query = reduce(operator.and_,[Q(item__keeper__id=int(element)) for element in keeper_and_list])
queryset = queryset.filter(keeper_and_query)
```

Result:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

**It is wrong.** It should be:

```
<QuerySet [<Frame: 4: Michael's news>, <Frame: 7: Michael's news>]>
```

As we can check:

```
>>> Frame.objects.filter(item__keeper__id=1)
<QuerySet [<Frame: 4: Michael's news>, <Frame: 7: Michael's news>]>
>>> Frame.objects.filter(item__keeper__id=2)
<QuerySet [<Frame: 4: Michael's news>, <Frame: 7: Michael's news>]>
```

Could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
queryset = Frame.objects.filter(
    item_keeper__id__in=keeper_and_list.split()
)
```

EDIT:

You need a `ManyToMany` relation since it is not possible for an Item to be keeped by two or more persons with a `ForeignKey`.

```
keeper = models.ManyToManyField(Person,
                           related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                           related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",
                           blank=False,
                           null=True,
                           on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                           verbose_name=_("Keeper"))
```

and

```
queryset = Frame.objects.filter()
for keeper in keeper_and_list.split():
    queryset = queryset.filter(item_keeper__id=keeper)
```

you have to loop through the item_keeper's because you can't use something like `Frame.objects.filter(item_keeper__id=1, item_keeper__id=2)`

Comment: This is not working. Reason: it will select with OR condition. In other words keeper will be either 1 or 2. I need AND condition!

Comment: Working. Thank you very much. ManyToManyField is not my case. Please, let's forget it. My relationship is One-to-Many. One person keeps several items. So, this is not important. But I can't catch why Q object can't be used here. Could you tell me?

Comment: Maybe it is something with the `reduce` over the `operator.and`. Try to print `str(queryset.query)` to see the SQL generated by the queryset

Comment: Strange. I can't post the select commands here: too much code. Stackoverflow forbids. There is a difference between the two selects. But the reason is a mystery to me. Well, anyway, thank you.